# Javascript? Jquery? Can't change width of Tumblr post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think this will be easy for you coders out there. I have tweaked a Tumblr theme and am pretty happy with the results except that I can't change the width of photos on a permalink (post) page.

Visit: http://hawkohphoto.tumblr.com/post/113115224219/summer-mornings-on-the-north-shore-of-hawaii and you'll see that the image's container is forcing a width of `426px` in the element of the image's container:

```html
<div class="tw_post tw_post_get tw_post_photo ocean masonry-brick" id="tw_post_113115224219" data-post-id="113115224219" style="width: 426px; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 0px;">
```

The same is happening with the Notes container to the right of the image:

```html
<div class="tw_post tw_perma_post tw_share_block masonry-brick" style="width: 426px; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 486px;">
```

I see one of the classes is `"masonry-brick"`. Is masonry javascript what is "forcing" the width on the element? I tried to override the .tw_post class with custom CSS and `!important` on `width: 100%` etc. but that changes the width on the posts of the homepage http://hawkohphoto.tumblr.com/

I want to leave the homepage the way it is: 4 columns (images are `244px` wide) and have the permalinks (single post pages) display the image at `100%` wide and the other notes container (`date`, `notes`, `highres`, etc.) would appear underneath the full size image at `100%` width.

How do I change the way those containers appear? I need to change their `width`, `positon`, etc. etc.

Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

The layout is using this JS library: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/index.html

Which is what is adding the "masonry-brick" class to the elements.

If you have access to the JavaScript for the layout, I would suggest looking for the part of the JS which is initialising the masonry layout. If you can find this method you can pass in an option to set a different width. This is the kind of thing you're looking for:

```
$('#container').masonry({
  // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  columnWidth: 240
});
```

Column width is an option you can pass in to change the width. Change this value and the size of your images will also update. You can view all of the options you can pass into masonry here: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/options.html

I suggest you experiment and play with the options until you get something you're happy with.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi James! Really appreciate your help. I am not sure that I have access tot he JavaScript for the layout. I see these referenced:

Comment: Hi James! Really appreciate your help. How do I get access to JavaScript. I see it referenced: <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/mcreuad/sPdmm0wl8/masonry.js"></script> Do I need to host it separately to edit it?

Comment: Hi @HaKoh - yes you would need access to the JS to edit it. "Static.tumblr.com" shows me files are being hosted as part of your theme  using Tumblr's file uploader. You would need to edit the JS files locally then re-upload your theme which includes the newly edited JS files. Also masonry.js might just be the JS library used for the layout. It might actually be initialized inside another JS file so you'll need to search through them individually for find that piece of code I referenced above. The key bit your searching for is ".masonry({". Hope this helps - sorry it's not a direct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add following two lines of jQuery in your single Image [page](http://hawkohphoto.tumblr.com/post/113115224219/summer-mornings-on-the-north-shore-of-hawaii).

1. `$(".tw_post_photo").css({'width':'100%',top:'auto',left:'auto',position:'relative'})`

   - It will make the Image to get 100% width
2. `$(".tw_share_block").css({top:'auto',left:'auto',position:'relative'})`

   - it will make the Notes block to get under the Image

Comment: I don't believe this will work because the masonry JS library will override the .css method you are using.

Comment: @James, Just try this yourself.
These lines SHOULD be executed at the end of Page. 
Do one thing, go to this - > http://hawkohphoto.tumblr.com/post/113115224219/summer-mornings-on-the-north-shore-of-hawaii page when execute these two lines in the console. You will get the result

Comment: Masonry recalculates the layout on update of the page, if the site is responsive as soon as it changes your two methods will get overriden as Masonry recalculates the page layout and applies new inline styling. You should use the options that Masonry comes with, not try to override them and cause conflicts.This is essentially bad practice.

Comment: @James , thanks, I didn't knew about the responsiveness of Masonry.